# How do I install ntfs-3g (ntfsprogs) manually on Ubuntu?

Tags: ntfs, ntfs-3g

To fix a SATA hard disk with a damaged NTFS file system, I tried to follow the process documented at [Ubuntu 13.04 is unable to mount a disk drive from ex-windows system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313872) which entails the use of the `ntfsprogs` utility.

I couldn't find the package `ntfsprogs` on the Ubuntu Software Center even after running `sudo apt-get update`. How should this package be installed?

Comment: Does the package `ntfs-3g` itself addresses the question? it's installable from Ubuntu rep. by the way.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov As that's probably the best way to get ntfs-3g on Ubuntu, you might want to post that (or something like it) as an answer.

Comment: On April 12, 2011 it was announced that Ntfsprogs project was merged with NTFS-3G 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntfsprogs 
# Do not do install ntfsprogs as on newer versions it uninstalls ntfs-3g
ntfsfix - fix common errors and force Windows to check NTFS  See also man ntfsfix

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `ntfsprogs` package was renamed to `ntfs-3g` in Ubuntu 13.04. Hence, from Ubuntu 13.04 onwards, one would use:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

However, this package lags a bit behind the latest version. Hence one may wish to compile from source to get the latest version.
<sup><sub>As of August 19, 2014, the latest version on the website is 2014.2.15, released on February 23, 2014, and the latest version on Ubuntu 14.04 is [2013.1.13AR.1-2ubuntu2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ntfs-3g).</sub></sup>

---

#### To compile from source:

Answered by OP as part of question, as a tutorial.

> This is a guide on how to do so...
>
> 1. Right now the `ntfs-3g` (`ntfsprogs`) package can be downloaded from: http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/
> 2. Once downloaded, unzip the archive and `cd` into the directory into which you unzipped it into.
> 3. Run the `./configure` command.
> 4. After the process completes, type `make` and hit return.
>
> After following the above mentioned steps, you are free to use the
> `ntfsfix` function to repair your broken NTFS file systems.

Comment: How do I run ntfsfix? Do I have to specify what hard drive/partition I want to fix? If so, how do I do that?

Edit: I found out how. For anyone wondering:  sudo ntfsfix /dev/<device name>