# How to install NTFS-3G Advanced through command line?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, software-installation, ntfs

I would like to install `NTFS-3G Advanced` since I need my Ubuntu installation to recognizing symbolic links created in Windows. [Their website](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/) indicates it can be installed by compiling the source code. However, I would prefer to install the software using `sudo apt-get install`. This thread:

[How do I install ntfs-3g (ntfsprogs) manually on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512461/how-do-i-install-ntfs-3g-ntfsprogs-manually-on-ubuntu)

shows how it can be done for standard `NTFS-3G` by running `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`. Can this be done for the advanced version?

**Edit 1**

Output of `apt search nfts-3g`:

```
ntfs-3g/trusty,now 1:2013.1.13AR.1-2ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  read/write NTFS driver for FUSE

ntfs-3g-dbg/trusty 1:2013.1.13AR.1-2ubuntu2 amd64
  read/write NTFS driver for FUSE (debug)

ntfs-3g-dev/trusty 1:2013.1.13AR.1-2ubuntu2 amd64
  read/write NTFS driver for FUSE (development)

ntfs-config/trusty 1.0.1-10 amd64
  Enable/disable write support for any NTFS devices
```

Comment: If only it has an installation candidate or repo!

Comment: @George Yeah, I figured there's an obvious solution, but I'm quite new to Ubuntu and have broken my installation (more than once) by having tried to do too much on my own. I did search for `NTFS-3G Advanced` in Ubuntu Software center and couldn't find anything. I don't actually know how, in general, people find the package names to install with `sudo apt-get install`. Could you explain more, please?

Comment: Ok search with `apt search ntfs-3g`

Comment: @George Just ran your suggestion and provided the output below the first edit.

Comment: Why not download the RPM, and then use https://askubuntu.com/q/2988/158442

Comment: You have the normal version installed let me search for a repo for the advanced version

Comment: @muru I thought the RPM files were for Fedora specifically given the label. I also didn't know they could be made into DEB files. Appreciate the alternate solution, though.