# Cannot access windows share: GUI "Unable to access location" terminal mount: cannot mount read only

Tags: 18.04, mount, samba

**At the moment I am unable to connect to a windows file share.**

**Environment**
 - System: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
 - Mount point is accessible from windows client

I tried via GUI / Files like in the [Ubuntu documentation: Browse files on a server or network share](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/nautilus-connect.html.en):

Files -> Other Location -> enter smb://serverIp/shareName 
[image: Error message opening network share: Unable to access location]

(The Timeout happens immediately ! )

In the terminal it looks like this:

```
sudo mount -v -r -t cifs -o username=domain/user,password=myPw //123.123.123.123/share /media/user/share/
mount: /media/user/share/: cannot mount //123.123.123.123/share read-only.
```

**How to debug / fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the same issue. It seems, there is no solution for the problem, so far. However, as stated [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390873&p=13764895#post13764895), a workaround is to revert the max allowed version. Proceed as follows:

1. Install samba client `sudo apt install smbclient`.
2. Edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and add line:
   `client max protocol = NT1`
   under `[global]`

This solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

That didn't worked for me so i kept searching and found the solution for this

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

then simple restart

refer to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512461/how-do-i-install-ntfs-3g-ntfsprogs-manually-on-ubuntu) for further information