# Laptop directly booting to Ubuntu, grub repair fails, BIOS screen won't show up. Is there a way I can access Windows again?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, asus, bios

I am an absolute beginner in Linux and I think I have trashed my laptop the first time I tried a Linux distro.

I am using Asus A555L.

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 to dual boot with Windows 10 (64 bit). It was working well up untill I forced shut my laptop down by long pressing the power button when I was in Windows.

Since then when I switch my laptop on, it goes directly to Ubuntu, forget GRUB, even the Asus screen won't show.

I tried grub repair from within Ubuntu, it fails. Here's the pastebin link:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yJWq6yRGzH

I have a Windows recovery flash drive but I can't access bios. Every single time I press f2 with the power button or ESC with the power button (the method that Asus website listed to access bios) my laptop just goes to a pitch black screen even though it's switched on.

My basic question is- Is there a way to access Windows again?

Also since the force shutdown incident, when in Ubuntu my screen keeps blinking. It was fine before that. Answers to similar questions say that it's because of the graphics card but it never created a problem up till now. Is it related?

Edit: It just needed another boot repair after completely draining out battery. Then went into windows safe mode, uninstalled a couple of things and was then able to access bios.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 13.04 is unable to mount a disk drive from ex-windows system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313872/ubuntu-13-04-is-unable-to-mount-a-disk-drive-from-ex-windows-system)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, was false alarm for me personally. For some reason, I simply had to hold the power button for much longer (about 15 seconds) so that it truly shutdown.

No explanation why, but it shut off the display, back-lit keyboard, etc, but apparently was not actually shut down, and was stuck in some limbo state.

Comment: That's what brought OP in this state, so is unlikely to be a solution to his problem.  Very Hard Reboot (VHR) is really bad advise; use [REISUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926461/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-reisub-reset-and-holding-down-the-power) instead. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  cc @karel

Comment: In my situation, which was in fact the solution to fix it, that did not work. Hence my answer. The state was not caused by a VHR, it was caused by an attempt to VHR without holding long enough.